# Numpy: Efficient matrix calculation A*xj where xj is row j in X

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

So the background to this "problem" is that I'm trying to optimize a large python project. I started timing the program and noticed that almost 50% of the run time is spent on a calculation similar to this one:

```
import numpy as np

# Example
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
X = np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0,0,0],np.eye(4),15000)

# Create a lambda function to use row based
F = lambda x: np.dot(A,x)

# Now calculating the value
answer = np.apply_along_axis(F, 1, X)

print answer.shape
```

I've tried to find a way to make this faster, but keep running into a wall. Is this really the optimal of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) on `X` and `A` to lose their second axes each. To input into `np.dot`, we will  use `X` as the first input and transpose `A` to bring its second axis to the front to be used as the second input.

Thus, we would have the output like so -

```
X.dot(A.T)
```

Runtime test for sample inputs listed in question -

```
In [192]: %timeit np.apply_along_axis(F, 1, X)
1 loops, best of 3: 185 ms per loop

In [193]: %timeit X.dot(A.T)
1000 loops, best of 3: 228 µs per loop

In [194]: np.allclose(np.apply_along_axis(F, 1, X), X.dot(A.T))
Out[194]: True # verified results against original code
```

Comment: Wow! This is an amazing speed increase!
I will link to this answer in the code, thanks :)

Comment: @piRSquared Hey! Well I saw that earlier and the points made there make sense to me, I liked it already :) I guess I was thinking about pointing out about `np.take` which helps if you have a lot of repeated indices. That point was made there by @hpaulj in the linked Q&A comments I guess. So, in all that Q&A alongwith the comments make the discussion on the topic pretty comprehensive. Good job on researching those things!

Comment: @piRSquared Ah one more thing I think I missed out on  - Did you look into getitem method? I am not familiar with it and not sure if it could be used there, but I have seen people use it. I don't know if that's gonna do any good on that topic, but could be worth a look at the least!

Comment: I will look into it